# How can I run glmark2 on the dedicated GPU?

Tags: gpu, amdgpu, benchmarks, dual-graphics

My laptop has a dedicated GPU, it is an *AMD Radeon HD 6300*. How can I test it with `glmark2`?
By default it is using the *iGPU*. `glmark2` man page doesn't show an option to choose the *dGPU*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Launch the benchmark using the dGPU with the `DRI_PRIME=1` option:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 glmark2
```

Edit : This answer is from mid 2018 when Xorg was the default session.

This means the solution is valid if the system is running a Xorg session.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you @cl-netbox

Comment: didn't work for me on ubuntu 21.10

Comment: Also did not work on (x)ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: didn't work for me on ubuntu 22.04. answer by @demaniak did work.

Comment: @rrosa (and demaniak and fccoelho) : You are running a Wayland session, correct ? Didn't you see that I posted the answer five years ago ? At that time the default session was Xorg ! So - "didn't work for me" (and a downvote) might not be appropriate ... right ? :)

Comment: i'm sorry for that, the comment was suggested by askubuntu automation. i thought it was protocol to explain why. Regarding the downvote, I was trying to get the "selected answer" (or at least the one with most votes) to be the one that works today. i've removed the downvote, didn't intend to be offensive.

Comment: Thank you @rrosa ! :)

Comment: This is working on Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS =)

Answer (score 4):

I'm on Xubuntu (22.04 Jammy).
My laptop has an AMD Integrated graphics chip, and a nVidia RTX3070 discrete graphics accelerator.

I have the proprietary nVidia drivers installed.

This worked for me:

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glmark2
```

Ref: [How NVIDIA On-Demand option works in NVIDIA X Server Settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201072/how-nvidia-on-demand-option-works-in-nvidia-x-server-settings)

Note: I should also maybe mention:

- BIOS graphics is set to Hybrid
- in nvidia-settings it is set to "On Demand"

Comment: One weird thing though - the glmark2 score when run with the AMD integrated graphics, was for some reason significantly higher than when running with the above settings. Like 9806 vs 2537.

Comment: this has crashed my Xorg session :-o