# nvidia-smi works, but glxinfo show OpenGL uses Intel graphics card; Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, opengl

I want to play a game using the discrete graphics on my notebook. I don't care about the Intel graphic card - I just want to use exclusively NVidia.

```bsh
$ nvidia-smi
Mon Mar 23 20:40:58 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 860M    On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  4046MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```bsh
$ glxinfo |grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

```bsh
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

```bsh
$ lspci | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
```

Out of desperation I have bbswitch installed, which shows ON even when I turn it OFF.

```bsh
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam # cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch 
0000:01:00.0 ON
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam # tee /proc/acpi/bbswitch <<<OFF
OFF
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam # cat /proc/acpi/bbswitch 
0000:01:00.0 ON
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam # prime-select query
nvidia
```

I used to have bumblebee configured on this machine, but it does not function properly anymore (and removing it does not affect the rendering).

```bsh
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam # service bumblebeed stop
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam # bumblebeed 
[  821.692186] [INFO]bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
[  821.692614] [ERROR]Failed to unload module 'nvidia' (ref count: 15).
^C[  882.413474] [WARN]Received Interrupt signal.
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam 5 # service bumblebeed start
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam # service bumblebeed status
● bumblebeed.service - Bumblebee C Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bumblebeed.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-03-23 20:52:34 CET; 1s ago
 Main PID: 10898 (bumblebeed)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/bumblebeed.service
           └─10898 /usr/sbin/bumblebeed

Mar 23 20:52:34 eevee-G551JM systemd[1]: Started Bumblebee C Daemon.
Mar 23 20:52:34 eevee-G551JM bumblebeed[10898]: [  903.313579] [INFO]/usr/sbin/bumblebeed 3.2.1 started
Mar 23 20:52:34 eevee-G551JM bumblebeed[10898]: [  903.314010] [ERROR]Failed to unload module 'nvidia' (ref count: 15).
root@eevee-G551JM:/home/adam # apt install xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440 is already the newest version (440.64.00-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```bsh
$ cd /etc/modprobe.d/
$ ag nvidia
blacklist-framebuffer.conf
19:blacklist nvidiafb

bumblebee.conf
5:# do not automatically load nouveau as it may prevent nvidia from loading
7:# do not automatically load nvidia as it's unloaded anyway when bumblebeed
10:blacklist nvidia
11:blacklist nvidia-current
12:blacklist nvidia-legacy-304xx
13:blacklist nvidia-legacy-340xx
15:blacklist nvidia
16:blacklist nvidia-current
17:blacklist nvidia-current-updates
...
```

```bsh
root@eevee-G551JM:/etc/modprobe.d # cat /etc/modules
i915
bbswitch
```

```bsh
$ cat /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf

[bumblebeed]
VirtualDisplay=:8
KeepUnusedXServer=false
ServerGroup=bumblebee
TurnCardOffAtExit=false
NoEcoModeOverride=false
Driver=
XorgConfDir=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.d
XorgBinary=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg

[optirun]
Bridge=auto
VGLTransport=proxy
PrimusLibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
AllowFallbackToIGC=false

[driver-nvidia]
KernelDriver=nvidia
PMMethod=auto
LibraryPath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
XorgModulePath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg,/usr/lib/xorg/modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules/input
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia

[driver-nouveau]
KernelDriver=nouveau
PMMethod=auto
XorgConfFile=/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nouveau
```

Can someone please explain me, how is that the `nvidia-smi` sees the graphic card, and yet xorg does not use it? It is very interesting that this is possible in the first place, but how to turn the system back to the state when all graphics is rendered by the nvidia (or better yet, that the bumblebee works)?

Answer (score 1):

glxinfo is a mesa utility, mesa is the GPU driver for Intel, Amd, VMware and Raspbery PI. Therefore it only delivers information about these GPUs.

Comment: the command for Nvidia is `nvidia-settings -g`

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the *Nvidia On-Demand* profile (especially if you're using an external monitor). Switching the profile to *Nvidia (Performance Mode)* in `nvidia-settings` solves the same problem for me.

From what I took from [How NVIDIA On-Demand option works in NVIDIA X Server Settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201072/how-nvidia-on-demand-option-works-in-nvidia-x-server-settings), the `On-Demand` profile allows dynamic switching of Nvidia, but it is limited to the laptop screen, while the `Performance Mode` use Nvidia to render everything and works on the external monitor.