# How do you offload a flatpak application to run on the nvidia graphics card when using prime?

Tags: nvidia-prime, flatpak

For some flatpak applications, it is better to use the dedicated GPU but how do you ensure that PRIME is offloading correctly when you cant run the usual testing commands inside the sandboxed applciations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Check that PRIME offloading is working

1. This is better answered in this question: https://askubuntu.com/a/1316539/253247
2. Install the [flatpak GPUViewer application](https://flathub.org/apps/details/io.github.arunsivaramanneo.GPUViewer).

## Set Application for offloading

Then you must change add the required environment variables in order to activate the GPU offloading:

#### via cli

```
# for OPENGL
flatpak override --env="__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia" full.application.Name
# for vulkan
flatpak override --env="__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1" full.application.Name

# for our testing we will do OpenGL with the GPUViewer application
flatpak override --env="__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia" io.github.arunsivaramanneo.GPUViewer
```

#### Flatseal

[image: flatseal setting GPUViewer to use PRIME offloading]

## Testing

Launch GPUViewer and go to the OpenGL tab, You should see the Nvidia graphics cards selected. If it still shows the Intel card then the offloading is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that u enable Nvidia Prime Offloading [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PRIME)

Test:

```bash
$ prime-run glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL renderer'
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2
```

Than run command:

```bash
flatpak override --user --device=dri --env=__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 --env=__VK_LAYER_NV_optimus=NVIDIA_only --env=__GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia org.blender.Blender
```

Run Blender. Do something.

Check dGPU Usage:

```bash
watch -n 1 nvidia-smi
```

Comment: Nice little touch for Vulkan.