# Lutris stopped launching games after Mesa Update

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, wine, games, lutris

I've been using lutris to play games through wine for about a month now, and it worked really good. No problem whatsoever, until yesterday.

After a big graphic drivers update, the games stopped launching. The two games i currently have installed, that worked before for sure and that stopped working are Under The Waves and Frostpunk.

Both their logs contain the same errors, which are the following:

```
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
MESA: error: Failed to query drm device.
glx: failed to create dri3 screen
failed to load driver: iris
failed to open /dev/dri/card0: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
failed to load driver: iris
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto: 
gamemodeauto:
```

I'll also add that i am using the flatpack version of lutris, and I'l using a NVidia GPU with the 535 drivers installed and up to date.

If anyone know what's the cause of the problem, please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mesa is not required for Nvidia. Iris is the Mesa driver for your Intel integrated GPU. You would want to find a way to force the games to use the Nvidia GPU

Comment: Would ya know how to do that? I can't seem to find it in the LUtris options, or in the games configurations

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1316567/1004020 for flatpak, or https://askubuntu.com/a/1089386/1004020 globally